# unexpected results from solr response

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am unable to get the correct response from solr search. when i use below url

http://localhost/solr/collection1/select?q=dubai%20at&wt=json&df=search_string

i should get the record related to this search_string "Atlantis The Palm The Palm Islands Dubai United Arab Emirates"

but i never get this. how can i improve the accuracy of the query.because the return data contains "Dubai Luxury Stay - Downtown Dubai Dubai United Arab Emirates" and "Holiday Inn Dubai - Downtown Dubai Dubai United Arab Emirates"
and i think they should have much less priority than "Atlantis The Palm The Palm Islands Dubai United Arab Emirates"

is there any way to increase the accuracy

Answer (score 0):

From the Strings alone, I don't see why *"Atlantis The Palm The Palm Islands Dubai United Arab Emirates"* should have higher priority than *"Dubai Luxury Stay - Downtown Dubai Dubai United Arab Emirates"* that has *"dubai"* 3 times in the text.

If you have an explicit ranking of your documents (based on reviews, price or something like that) that you want reflected in Solr, you can boost your documents when indexing: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts

If you don't get a match at all for the wanted document (not even a low-ranked one), then it is probably because you also have *"at"* in your query and that *at* does not occur in the wanted document at all.

Comment: "Atlantis The Palm The Palm Islands Dubai United Arab Emirates" here i have "at" in "Atlantis" and dubai is it possible to rank it higher than strings which don't have "at" and only have dubai. i want solr to see both "dubai" and 'at"  with same priority

Comment: can you please guide me on above comment @toke Eskildsen

Comment: You are implying automatic prefix-matching. For that you need to add a leading NGram analyzer to your field setup: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-EdgeN-GramTokenizer